# Springer Nature (sn-basic): can't add acronyms

Tags: glossaries, springernature

I am using Springer Nature's `sn-basic` document class. I followed [this article](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Glossaries) to add acronym. It doesn't add the acronym but added 16-17 errors.

```
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries
\newacronym{PINN}{PINN}{Physics-informed neural networks}


\begin{document}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]
```

Errors:

```
1. Package xkeyval Error: key `noglossaryindex' undefined.
2. LaTeX hooks Error: Missing \PopDefaultHookLabel.
3. Package xkeyval Error: key `nomain' undefined.
4. Package xkeyval Error: key `nostyles' undefined.
5. Package xkeyval Error: key `notree' undefined.
6. Package xkeyval Error: key `nosuper' undefined.
7. Package xkeyval Error: key `nolong' undefined.
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's the standard problem: Springer Nature classes load the completely useless `program` package which does very nasty things.

Disable its loading.

```
\expandafter\def\csname ver@program.sty\endcsname{3000/12/31}

\documentclass{sn-jnl}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

\makeglossaries

\newacronym{PINN}{PINN}{Physics-informed neural networks}


\begin{document}

\gls{PINN}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Acronyms]

\end{document}
```

[image]

I see no reason whatsoever for inflicting all users of Springer Nature classes the loading of `algorithm2e` and `program`. Besides, the loading order of packages is not the best, because `hyperref` is called earlier than it should. Protest fiercely.

When running a recent LaTeX version (at least 2020-10-01), you may replace the first cryptic line with the less cryptic

```
\makeatletter
\disable@package@load{program}{\typeout{Not loading program.sty}}
\makeatother
```

Leave the second argument empty if you don't want messages about this.